# ensure text remains visible during webfont load bootstrap glyphicons

Tags: css, fonts, pagespeed

Whatever I did, I couldn't solve this issue. Google Pagespeed is still displaying the same message.

I've tried with many different code and I think this is the right one.
Appreciate if someone can tell me what I'm missing.

```
<link rel="preload" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
<style>
    @font-face {
    font-display: swap;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src: url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2');
}
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap v3.3.4: I use the Halflings font locally and just added "font-display:swap;" to the respective @font-face directive in bootstrap.min.css.

```
@font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';src:url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');src:url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');font-display:swap;}
```

After that, Google Pagespeed doesn't complain anymore.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I've done but it doesn't seem it's working. Any idea would be appreciated. <style>
        @font-face {
            font-display: swap;
            font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
            src: url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2');
        }
    </style>